# Javascript-Json: How to Access dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, list

I'm using json to auto populate a drop down list.
Depending on what the user selects, I want to auto populate two more fields.

Example: 
 
1.) User selects Apple From a drop down list ( pulled from json) 
 
2.) secondary drop down list gives selection of different apples (pulled from the same json file)

 
Now, I want to take the data from 2.) and use that to fill out two more fields automatically
 
3.) Apple c. is [6 oz] (I could store that store that in a json file too?)
4.) Apple c. is [3.99$] (I could store that store that in a json file too

Now, I have step 1.) and 2.) done.

I can't figure out how to bind the selection from 2.) in a way that corresponds to 3.) and 4.) automatically.

My Code:
data.json

```
    {
"apple": "a, b, c, d,",
"orange": "1,2,3,4,",
"banana": "a1, b2, c3, d4,"
   }
```

This currently utilizes the following to auto populate a dropdown:

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#json-one").change(function() {

            var $dropdown = $(this);

            $.getJSON("jsondata/data.json", function(data) {

                var key = $dropdown.val();
                var vals = [];

                switch(key) {

                    case 'apple':
                        vals = data.apple.split(",");
                        break;

                    case 'orange':
                        vals = data.orange.split(",");
                        break;
                    case 'banana':
                        vals = data.banana.split(",");
                        break;
                    case 'base':
                        vals = ['Please choose from above'];
                }

                var $jsontwo = $("#json-two");
                $jsontwo.empty();
                $.each(vals, function(index, value) {
                    $jsontwo.append("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                });

            });
        });


    });
</script>
```

This all works fine.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the value/type of fruit the user selected. I want to get that value, and depending on what that is, I want to display information about that type of fruit.

Comment: can you change the data.json file to return the sizes and prices as well?

Comment: @DavidStetler I can definitely change the data.json file. I love what you did below. But how would I go about accessing the data with the script I wrote. And how would I call the secondary data to actually display the secondary information?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have your data structured more like this:

```
{
"apples" : {
    "a" : {
        "size" : "6oz",
        "price" : "3.99"
    }
    "b" : {
        "size" : "7oz",
        "price" : "4.25"
    }
    "c" : {
        "size" : "3oz",
        "price" : "2.50"
    }
    "d" : {
        "size" : "6oz",
        "price" : "3.99"
    }
}

"oranges" : {
    "a" : {
        "size" : "6oz",
        "price" : "3.99"
    }
    "b" : {
        "size" : "7oz",
        "price" : "4.25"
    }
    "c" : {
        "size" : "3oz",
        "price" : "2.50"
    }
    "d" : {
        "size" : "6oz",
        "price" : "3.99"
    }
}
}
```

This would be a good first step.